# jquery ajax form collection and other key/value pairs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, formcollection

well since I never got an answer to my question here: [checkboxes and radio buttons in MVC FormCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397238/checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-in-mvc-formcollection)

I thought I'd take a different approach and just find my radio button value client side, and pass it as a different name/value pair in my ajax call...it was a great idea, but I can't get it to work.

using this works fine to pass my form collection:

```
formCollection = $(':input');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/mycontroller/mymethod",
            data: formCollection,
            dataType: "text",
            success: showConfirm,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

but when I try and change my data to an object like this:

```
formCollection = $(':input');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/mycontroller/mymethod",
            data: ({collection: formCollection}),
            dataType: "text",
            success: showConfirm,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

it won't fly.  I need to do that so ultimately I can use this:

```
formCollection = $(':input');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/mycontroller/mymethod",
            data: ({collection: formCollection, radiobutton: radiobuttonValue}),
            dataType: "text",
            success: showConfirm,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

my action method on the controller looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult mymethod(FormCollection collection)
        {
}
```

any ideas why when I change the data, it doesn't work?

Comment: what does `FormCollection` actually contain? -- see also http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server

Comment: formCollection = $(':input');  it contains all of the input fields on the page...

Comment: So you're trying to submit a jQuery object, instead of data? Try using `formCollection = $('form').serialize()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: ok serializing the formCollection did the trick.  Note to others though, it still can't be passed like data: ({ whatever: whatever })...it has to be passed like data: whatever.serialize().  If you make a "real" answer out of this mblase, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `formCollection = $('form').serialize()` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize

This will produce a string that looks like a GET query string, which you can use directly in your first code sample.

Answer (score 0):

//first try and get the value of the field , that resolve the issue
formCollection = $(':input').val();